# Gatsby Plugin Sitemap does not generate sitemap for my website

Tags: gatsby, sitemap, wordpress-rest-api

The below code doesn't generate sitemap of my Gatsby website. I am using wordpress as my CMS. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

```
`gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
      options: {
        output: `./expatsitemap.xml/`,
        exclude: [`/category/*`],
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                siteUrl
              }
            }

            allSitePage {
              edges {
                node {
                  path
                }
              }
            }
        }`,
        serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) =>
          allSitePage.edges.map(edge => {
            return {
              url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.path,
              changefreq: `daily`,
              priority: 0.7,
            }
          })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your main domain as `host: "https://www.yourwebsite.com",` in the `options`